Подключение к БД oracle
Всем привет.
Столкнулся с такой проблемой:
не могу подключиться к БД Oracle.

Настройки подлкючения:

Если пробовать через SQLPlus, то:

Сами службы:

Пытался ставить 23c, 12c,22c, 11g
Как итог, подключиться не удалось.
Прошу оказать помощь.

Добавьте в вопрос настройки листнера БД. Первая ошибка явно говорит, что у вас sid бд неверный и так же что было передано для формирования строки connectionid + откуда подключаетесь

@SwaD, подскажите, пожалуйста, где эти настройки найти? Если не ошибаюсь при инсталляции sid был xe. Пробовал еще подключиться по Service name orcl - тоже без результатно. Пытаюсь подключиться через SQL Developer

@SwaD, нашел конфиги сервера: cloneDBCreation.log,CloneRmanRestore.log,postDBCreation.log,postScripts.log,XE.bat.log Вот кусок из лога: SQL> @C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\rdbms\admin\dbmssml.sql;
SP2-0310: unable to open file "C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\rdbms\admin\dbmssml.sql"
SQL> @C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\rdbms\admin\dbmsclr.plb;
SQL> DROP PUBLIC DATABASE LINK DBMS_CLRDBLINK;
SP2-0640: Not connected
SQL> CREATE PUBLIC DATABASE LINK DBMS_CLRDBLINK USING 'ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA';
SP2-0640: Not connected
